# How to use blenders built in HDRI's?

Tags: rendering, light, lighting, hdri

How do I use blender's built in HDRI's? I can see their effect in the viewport and I like it, but when I render, it only uses the other lights I have manually added. I have circled where I am getting the HDRI from.

Thanks for any help!
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use 2.8's default HDRi's in renders?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128499/how-to-use-2-8s-default-hdris-in-renders)

Comment: It kind of does, but I don't actually want the hdri environment to show in the render, just the lighting that results from it... Does that make sense  I just want it to render as it looks in the viewport

Comment: Go to render properties > Film > Transparent

Comment: Or this https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/148387/19156

Comment: Alright that's what I need! the only problem is I can't find the installation directory... How do I acces that? It says they are under C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\datafiles\studiolights\world but I don't see that anywhere

Comment: "Old" question.. so maybe it is not 2.80 now but your current blender's version (2.90, maybe): change it in the file path. For 2.90, would be: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.90\2.90\datafiles\studiolights\world or around that depending on the way program is installed for you

Comment: How do I access that file path though? Lol, I literally have no idea... Thanks for your help and patience haha

Comment: Well... navigate progressively in your directories from c:/program files, etc...

Comment: That's the problem, nothing comes up when I start with C:/ so I figured I must be looking in the wrong place lol. I'm on macOS if that makes a difference...

Comment: ok, I cannot help you for macOS... : (

Comment: I actually just got it with some help from my dad lol, thanks again for the link, that's exactly what I needed!!

Comment: The base path for macOS should be `/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/MacOS/Blender`.